# QML Error: Unknown method return type: std::string

Tags: c++, qml

I use QML. Ihave this c++ code

```
#include <QObject>

class ShowTime : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ShowTime(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE std::string whatToShow(int index);

private:
    std::string mWhatToShow = "";
};
```

In QML I do this:

```
Text {
                font.pixelSize: 25
                height: 30
                text: showTime.whatToShow(index)
            }
```

But as a result I get an error:

> **Error: Unknown method return type: std::string**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried including the header file `#include<string>`, maybe? `:P`

Comment: You need to register std::string as metatype

Comment: @deW1 What is a _metatype_?

Comment: I guess so, you need to have `#include<string>` bummer isn't it. `whatToShow(int index)` receive integer as parameter, so might need to change `std::string mWhatToShow ="";` to `std::int` I will try to run the code later. brb

Comment: I think you should use `QString` not sure if QML understands std, you can easily do this: `return QString::fromStdString(your_std_string);`

Comment: @DanielLangr https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1 / https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Comment: @Duck Dodgers #include<string> 
already done, does not work

Comment: @deW1 May edit my code for registering  metatype std::string ?

Comment: @Amfasis already done, does not work

Comment: @Orest put `qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");` in your main.cpp, you can probably leave out the "std::string" parameter, but some classes needed it, I don't recall which right now

Comment: Registering `std::string` won't help if the QML engine doesn't know what to do with it.
Use `QString`, it works

Comment: True, I missed how he used it in QML due to the formatting.

Answer (score -1):

@GrecKo Yes it helped. Thank you.
I changed std::string to QString.